# UIButton appearance layer in appdelegate not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, layer

I want to make all the buttons in the app as a rounded button.

But UIButton appearance does not change the layer properties in appdelegate:

```
[[[UIButton appearance] layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[[UIButton appearance] layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
```

What's wrong?

many thanks

Comment: I would recommend subclassing UIButton to meet your needs.

Comment: You are right vivekvasani... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As this is an old question but it came up as related, you can't change the layer properties using appearance. For a complete list, you can check [this page](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521).

For the UIButton, the valid options are:

```
//UIView

@property(nullable, nonatomic,copy) UIColor *backgroundColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

//UIButton

@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentEdgeInsets UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

- (void)setTitleColor:(nullable UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
- (void)setTitleShadowColor:(nullable UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(nullable UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Answer (score 2):

If somebody is looking for a swift solution to this question, even 6 years after, as appearance can't manage `CALayer`, you can make an extension to `UIView` that will work with `appearance`, the trick is to use the `dynamic` keyword on `@objc` variables, that will force swift to use these implementations :

```
extension UIView {
    @objc dynamic  var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = self.layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set(color) {
            self.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic  var borderWidth: NSNumber? {
        get { return NSNumber(value: Float(self.layer.borderWidth))}
        set(width) {
            self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(width?.floatValue ?? 0)
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic  var cornerRadius: NSNumber? {
        get { return NSNumber(value: Float(self.layer.cornerRadius))}
        set(radius) {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius?.floatValue ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```